# Android - No Context available in non-UI Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my project, I have an Adapter `D` into a non-UI Fragment `C` into a UI fragment `B` witch himself is instanced by an Activity `A`:

> Activity `A` > UI Fragment `B` > non-UI Fragment `C` > Adapter `D`

The non-UI Fragment `C` is retained with `setRetainInstance(true)` to manage HTTP requests and other things.

When a configuration change occurs, Activity `A` is destroyed with UI Fragment `B`, but the non-UI fragment `C` is retained with his Adapter `D`.

My problem is when the Adapter `D.getView(position, view, parent)` method is invoked by the `B` ListView to inflate his content, I have no `non-NULL` `Context` available to inflate view and do other actions. I tried to get him with with `getActivity` or `parent.getContext`.

I would like to find my error...

---

Edit:

I tried to attach the non-UI Fragment `C` to the UI-Fragment `B` with `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`:

```
public final FragmentManager getChildFragmentManager()
```

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

I obtain:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments
```

So I suppose it is not possible?

Comment: Show us your logcat and your getView

Comment: I have a NullPointerException on every thing which try to get a valid context

Answer (score 0):

Validate your call with:

```
if(!isAdded() || isDetached){
    return;
}
```

Probably you're calling getView using a thread or handler that only finishes when your fragment is already detached.

Comment: Do you have any async tasks or handlers inside your fragment?

Comment: Then your async task is finishing after your fragment is detached. Add the code I posted after your `onPostExecute`